# Preloading videos within a table before displaying it

Tags: javascript, jquery, preload

I have a table containing html video elements, making up part of a slideshow. I periodically loas an updated version load this table into the DOM using javascript, which works fine.

Ideally though I would preload these videos such that the new table is not visible at all until the content has been loaded, and then when the table is displayed, they all appear immediately.

All my attempts so far end up with the table populating the videos over the course of a second- which is functional but not very pretty....

Comment: I do not see a stated question.  Nor do I see any provided logic of any attempts you have made, related to whatever the question is.

Comment: Ouch. Ok...well the question is whether there is a way that I can replace an existing table with a new one in javascript (yes), but only make that replacement when the content within the new table has already loaded (unknown). So far I have tried loading the videos individually using javascript to set the src on a video element, then calling load on that element, before making the table swap, but in doing this it appears that the video data is still not cached

Comment: I thought I had this worked out - I loaded the "next" table in a div with display:none and then toggled the active and the none div one ahead of what I wanted to display to the user. This looked like it was going to work...but currently any video loaded into the display:none div will not play once that div is made visible

Comment: Ah - fixed - the "preload a second display:none" div did work after all - I just had a typo...